# How to get value from consul key from https end point using curl

Tags: consul

I am using Jenkins job to automatically update the consul key using HTTPS endpoint. The syntax I am using to update the consul key `a/b/c` is mentioned below:

```
curl -f -s --show-error "https://example.com/a/b/c?AdminKey=xxxxx&token=yyyyyyy&value=nnn"
```

(Here key is `a/b/c`)

The above command works fine and updates consul key `a/b/c` to value `nnn`.

Now I want to fetch the value of same key `a/b/c` in a variable then how I can fetch using curl command similar to what I have used for updating key?

Note: I have tried curl command such as

```
v1=curl -f -s --show-error "https://example.com/a/b/c?AdminKey=xxxxx&token=yyyyyyy"
```

where `v1` is a temp variable to hold the value. But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a key using this syntax.

```sh
curl --request PUT --fail --silent --show-error "http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/a/b/c?token=<token>" --data 'nnn'
```

The value can then be retrieved and stored in a variable using this command.

```sh
export VARIABLE=$(curl --fail --silent --show-error "http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/a/b/c?token=<token>&raw")
```

See https://www.consul.io/api-docs/kv for more info on the supported arguments for these API calls.